# Persisting multiple new associated objects in a self-referenced table with Doctrine2 and Symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I'm quite new to Doctrine2 which I'm currently using in a Symfony2 project.
I'm trying to persist entities with a self-referencing foreign key such as the category example of the Doctrine documentation (http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-self-referencing). There is probably a very easy solution to this but I just couldn't find it anywhere on the web.

For some reason, the value for the parent_id is not automatically stored by Doctrine (it's null), although I can access the id value of the object I am assigning as a parent.
Some code will probably be straightforward. Here's the relevant part :

The entity definition :

```
class Area
{
     // id, name, type, etc...

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Area", inversedBy="sub_areas", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent_area_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $parent_area;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Area", mappedBy="parent_area", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $sub_areas;

    /**
     * Set parent area
     *
     * @param obj $area
     */
    public function setParentArea(Area $area)
    {
        $this->aera = $area;
    }

    // Other getters and setters, etc.
}
```

In the action :

```
$results = array();

foreach($area_types as $key => $type) {
    $area = new Area();
    $area->setType($type);
    $area->setName($location->getAddressComponent($type));

    if(isset($parent_area)) {
        $area->setParentArea($parent_area);
    }

    $this->em->persist($area);
    $parent_area = $area;
    $results[] = $area->getId();
}

$this->em->flush();
```

The results array will output the assigned ids in Twig. I also tried using :

```
 $area->setParentAreaId($parent_area->getId());
```

Could anyone explain how Doctrine manages the database persistence sequence of self-referenced objects ?

Comment: Red alert! You are using self-referencing to represent a hierarchy. If this hierarchy can be deep, (can it), then you're going to have some problems when writing your queries. You can [read here why](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model) , and use [Doctrine Extensions](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions) in order to be able to use the Nested Set model for representing your areas and avoid many headaches.

Comment: You're right. Although I finally got it work this was not a good approach at all. Cheers

Comment: Would you mind explaining how you did it?